# How to shutdown redis-cli by command line on windows?

Tags: redis

I'm trying shutdown redis by redis-cli but

> C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli.exe
>
> redis 127.0.0.1:6379> shutdown
>
> (error) ERR Errors trying to SHUTDOWN. Check logs.

I opened log file but this is empty directory.
How to shutdown it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAVE and NOSAVE modifiers
It is possible to specify an optional modifier to alter the behavior of the command. Specifically:

`SHUTDOWN SAVE` will force a DB saving operation even if no save points are configured.

`SHUTDOWN NOSAVE` will prevent a DB saving operation even if one or more save points are configured. (You can think at this variant as an hypothetical ABORT command that just stops the server).

If it doesnt work find the ProccessId of the exe from taskmanager and kill it using CMD

For example `C:\>Taskkill /PID 26356 /F`
where 26356 is the proccessid

Comment: I tried ``SHUTDOWN NOSAVE`` but it throw an error

``(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'shutdown' command``

Comment: Edit made.. check it out